# angular-dashboard-framework Sortable.create return undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run the source code of the angular-dashboard-framework demo (https://github.com/sdorra/angular-dashboard-framework/tree/master/sample)

I'm getting following error:

```
Sortable.create function returns undefined.
```

Comment: have you got angular installed and in the correct location as specified in the project's html file, along with all the other js dependencies?

Comment: yes i did, same as demo

Comment: Did you build from source like in https://github.com/sdorra/angular-dashboard-framework ?

Comment: I'm not sure where you are getting this error. I've just cloned it and it's working. Can you say where you see this error, if in console can you paste the whole line? Are you running windows by any chance?

Comment: @EdwardKnowles, yes,he is running windows

Comment: no, i download the source code and tried to get the dependencies manually, without node and bower

Comment: There lies your problem.

Comment: Edward Knowles, yes i'm using windows, the error is not showed in console. by debugging its in column.js line 131, Sortable.create function returns undefined